# Custom PHPFox V2 Landing Page

Tags: php, frameworks, social-networking, phpfox

I have a social network built using [PHPFox](http://phpfox.com) and it's proving to be quite a challenge to change the default landing page. Does anyone know how I can change the default core.index-visitor landing page without having to adjust all the menus and everything? Would it be easier to just upload all the files for my custom landing page then redirect the apache configuration file to point to the new landing? Or can I do that from the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by editing the welcome blocks in the admincp.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `welcome.html.php` file
to change landing page

in user module

```
user/template/default/block/welcome.html.php
```

May that helps you